# Disable warning message of pylint

Tags: code-analysis, pylint

Checking code with `pylint` shows so many messages about variable names as follows:

> Invalid name "getCurrentChannel" for type method (should match
>   [a-z_][a-z0-9_]{2,30}$)

How can I disable these messages ?

Answer (score 0):

```
pylint --disable=C0103 filename
```

Running this command will not show messages for "Invalid variable name".