# How do I avoid pylint warning C0103

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

When I write Python in VSCode I get a lot of pylint warnings but I don't know how to solve them. I've googled the codes and I think I need to structure my code differently but I don't know how. I don't want to disable the warnings, I want to write better code.

Example code in `test.py`

```
from unityagents import UnityEnvironment

env = UnityEnvironment(file_name='FrozenLakeGym')

state = env.reset(train_mode=True)

result = env.step(0)

print(result)

env.close()
```

On the first line I get `C0111:Missing module docstring`; and the next 3 lines each have `C0103:Constant name "" doesn't conform to UPPER_CASE naming style`

How should I be writing my programs?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/21779900/575530

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Pylint is assuming that `env`, `state` and `result` are all constant variables because they are defined on the module scope.

I would advise against following the instructions to uppercase your variable names - as none of them actually are constants.

An easy way around this, is to do what you're doing in a function

```
from unityagents import UnityEnvironment

def main():
    env = UnityEnvironment(file_name='FrozenLakeGym')
    state = env.reset(train_mode=True)
    result = env.step(0)
    print(result)
    env.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This has the added advantage of your code not being run just because you imported it.

Comment: That's what I'm looking for. Thank you. I also disabled `C0111` in my settings so I don't have to add docstrings either